# Your target project 'x' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'xx'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

.net core 3.0.
I have a  LibraryProject(SyWaterStandardLibrary), There's a DbContext.When I build new WebProject(WebApplicationTestLibrary) and using LibraryProject.

Startup:

```
  services.AddDbContext<LocalContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SMS"), 
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplicationTestLibrary"))
               );
```

When I execute: `add-migration init -context localcontext`

> An error has occurred:Your target project 'WebApplicationTestLibrary'
>   doesn't match your migrations assembly 'SyWaterStandardLibrary'.
>   Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.

This exception does not exist in .net core 2.2.
What's the matter, please.

Edit 1:
[WebApplicationTestLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNK5q.png)

[SyWaterStandardLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGJAU.png)

Comment: Have you checked the .net core versions match??

Comment: yes.I checked it.

Comment: I got the same error when I set the startup project and the target project as `WebApplicationTestLibrary`  and  `optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly("SyWaterStandardLibrary"))` , there is also have a suggestion to change your migrations assembly with `WebApplicationTestLibrary` to solve the problem . Make sure the startup project , the target project and migrationsAssembly are  the same.

Answer (score 44):

When you run any Entity Framework Core command from the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio, the default project must be your migration assembly `SyWaterStandardLibrary`. Here's a picture showing how to change it (here, my migration assembly is called `Model`):

[image: How to set the default project in the Package Manager Console]

Note that this is not the same as the startup project.

Comment: Thanks for your response。but I have only one option,just WebApplicationTestLibrary,No SyWaterStandardLibrary in options.

Comment: The WebApplicationTestLibrary Using the compiled DLL file reference

Answer (score 3):

Change target assembly

```
cd ../SyWaterStandardLibrary

dotnet ef --startup-project 
../WebApplicationTestLibrary/ migrations 
add Initial
```

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same Issue and this was the best and simple solution.**

My Folder Structure was as follows

```
|- Project.DataAccess
|--- ProjectDBContext.cs
|- Project.Presentation (Default Project)
|--- appsetting.json
|--- program.cs
```

The Problem Description:
As we would run migration from the presentation layer of the project migrations folder needs to be created somewhere in our solution so we need to specify our program that Use the DbContext from DataAccess Layer but keep the migration folder within the presentation layer in the solution.

Solution:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Project.Presentation")));
```

We need to specify the migration assembly project.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but these steps might help someone.

1. Define your DBContext class properly

   > public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions
   > options) : base(options) {
   > }
2. Add the required DB sets in the The DbContext class

> ```
> public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
> ```

3. Depending on the .Net version on Program.cs or Startup.cs , register the DbContext class

> ```
> builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
> ```

4. Set your Web project as your startup project
5. In the Package Manage Console (PMC) set the "Default project" to your project with the Data models you want to add to the database.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvJVL.png)
6. If you haven't already created the database first run the

> Update-Database

command. This will create the database. Check if it has created the DB.

7. Then run command

> Add-Migration AddProductsTableToDb

8. You should see the migration script created in a folder
9. Not to do the actual migration and create the table in the DB run the following command.

> Update-Database

Hope that helps