# Add Migrations to a class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class library that contains my DBContext class and the entity classes.

I am using the class library as a nuget package in other projects - not in the same solution.

My plan is to be able to run migrations from the projects and let the migrations be stored in the context class Library under a folder names "Migrations".

So, after including the nuget package into the web project, i modify my Startup.css as follows:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection"), m=>m.MigrationsAssembly("MyDbContextLibrary.Migrations")));
```

When I run this, I get the error message as follows

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyDbContextLibrary.Migrations, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I wish to get a guide on how to go about this.

What I am trying to achieve is such that all the migrations are contained in the DBContextLibrary so that any other project that includes it will have the migrations and can easily just run the "Update-Database" command without having to create separate migrations and another database. The plan is that all the projects can connect to the same database without having each project create their own database.

The project is running on EFCore 5.13 and ASP.Net Core 5

Please note, I already referred to the following SO questions and answer but yet to get a solution

Thank you

Comment: The `MigrationsAssembly` specifies the name of the assembly, not the namespace of the migrations. If your migrations are in the `MyDbContextLibrary` assembly, then don't add the `.Migrations` to the assembly name.

Comment: "Your target project 'MyCurrentProject' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'MyDbContextLibrary '. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyDbContextLibrary ")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the ..."

Comment: @RichardDeeming That is the error message I get when I remove the ".Migrations"

Comment: [Your target project 'x' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'xx'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265606/your-target-project-x-doesnt-match-your-migrations-assembly-xx-either-chan)

Comment: I have checked this, it does not provide a solution. The dropdown in the package manager console does not contain the library project. So there is no way I can change it to the MyDbContextLibrary